# "Caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully" error in Openshift

Tags: laravel, apache2, openshift

I'm running Laravel in openshift server (Lamp stack) . My server was offline for past two days. Then, I looked into the error log, It says `caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully`. But, It didn't give me more details. How to find the reason for the shutdown. I have attached the error log with this question.

```
- - - [13/Dec/2014:12:06:34 -0500] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) (internal dummy connection)"
- - - [13/Dec/2014:12:06:34 -0500] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) (internal dummy connection)"
[Sat Dec 13 12:06:34 2014] [notice] caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Mon Dec 15 01:15:31 2014] [notice] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context 

unconfined_u:system_r:openshift_t:s0:c6,c126
[Mon Dec 15 01:15:31 2014] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Mon Dec 15 01:15:31 2014] [notice] Digest: done
[Mon Dec 15 01:15:31 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) configured -- resuming normal operations
- - - [15/Dec/2014:01:15:32 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 302 268 "-" "-"
- - - [15/Dec/2014:01:15:38 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 302 268 "-" "-"
- - - [15/Dec/2014:01:15:41 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 302 268 "-" "-"
- - - [15/Dec/2014:01:15:44 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 302 268 "-" "-"
- - - [15/Dec/2014:01:15:47 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 302 268 "-" "-"
- - - [15/Dec/2014:01:15:49 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 302 268 "-" "-"
- - - [15/Dec/2014:01:15:52 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 302 268 "-" "-"
- - - [15/Dec/2014:01:15:55 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 302 268 "-" "-"
- - - [15/Dec/2014:01:15:58 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 302 268 "-" "-"
- - - [15/Dec/2014:01:16:04 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 302 268 "-" "-"
- - - [15/Dec/2014:01:16:07 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 302 268 "-" "-"
- - - [15/Dec/2014:01:16:10 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 302 268 "-" "-"
- - - [15/Dec/2014:01:16:14 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 302 268 "-" "-"
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 127.12.49.129:8080
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
```

Can anyone please help in finding the reason for the error ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: OpenShift runs on RHEL, not on ubuntu.  Can you clarify that part of your question please?  Are YOU running ubuntu + lamp stack locally, then deploying to OpenShift?

Comment: Sorry, It is not ubuntu. It is RHEL only.

Comment: It looks like whatever you are doing can't bind to your ip address & port on your gear, can you give more information on what cartridges you are using and if you are trying to bind to that ip/port manually with any software?  You also might try issuing a "stop" and "start" via the rhc command line tools to see if that helps (not a restart)

Comment: We are using PHP 5.4, MongoDB, MySql cartridge

Comment: Try doing a force stop with the rhc command line tool, then a start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SIGWINCH is also used by some services that need to restart Apache when rotating logs, nightly jobs, etc.

That doesn't explain the problem you're currently having, but I think it might be something else running on your server that's restarting Apache – or it might not be related to your problem at all.